# How to get cerificate for socket.io without domain (I dont prefer self-signed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

how I currently host my socket.io server:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(port);
```

and I am new at this.. so I would like some help..

Comment: Like, using my IP or something like that

Comment: Where are you hosting your application?

Comment: AWS is a possibility

Comment: I am hosting on windows, using socket.io, how can I do self signed tho?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, SSL is tied to the domain name, not the public IP address.

I would reccomend using a node.js playground, like [glitch](https://glitch.com) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io).

These allow you to host nodejs servers without handling certificates -- you can then manage it once your ready.